# How do I connect Azure SQL to Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019

I’m doing a project for school that requires building a function IT project. I’ve got the HTML, CSS, and SQL parts down pat. It’s the combination in Visual Studio 19 Mac that isn’t clicking for me.

How do I go about connecting my existing SQL database to my Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-content-reference-guide. This reference guide will point out [how to obtain the connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-content-reference-guide#get-adonet-connection-information-optional---sql-database-only) for your Azure SQL Database. You can use this connection string to add a connection via the SQL Server Object Explorer, (Ctrl+, Ctrl+S) in Windows, I assume it's (Cmd+, Cmd+S) on Mac, to be able to query your database from inside Visual Studio.

[image: sql-server-object-explorer]

The Add Connection diaglog will allow you to add your IP to the Firewall which is needed to access the database/server. This principal works the same for local network databases. Make sure you choose the correct Authentication type, e.g. Azure AD for Azure SDL, Windows for local network SQL Servers if so properly configured. You can always use SQL Server Auth for either one.